# Share a global variable across modules in Python

Tags: python, global-variables

I've 2 modules. I want to send the response to a server using a global variable `server`. When I try to send the data, it says `BROKEN PIPE`, which means connection has been lost. Hence the data is not able to send. What it does is that, while importing `tcp_driver` to `send_response` file, it again initializes the `server` variable and since it remains unconnected, hence return a BROKEN PIPE error.

How do I use the global variable `server` in order to send the data .

PS: I don't want to pass the server variable as an argument. Neither do I want to save the server variable into a 3rd module, thereby inheriting it from the 3rd module.

Following are my modules.

**tcp_driver.py**

```
import send_response

server = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET,socket.SOCK_STREAM)
server.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET,socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
server_address = (config.IP_ADD, config.PORT)

def main():
    while True:
        try :
            server.connect(server_address)  
            print "Connected"
            break
        except socket.error: # Tries to connect to the server until it is connected.
            print "Not Connected"
            continue

    response = "Hello Server"
    send_response.send_response_to_server(response)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

**send_response.py**

```
import tcp_driver

def send_response_to_server(response):
    try : server.send(response)
    except : tcp_driver.main() # if connection is broken, it tries to connect again.
```

Comment: Because its just a sample of my large code, which has been made modular. So, please response accordingly.

Comment: Also, if I put `send_response_to_server` to `tcp_driver` file and call `send_response_to_server` from another module, it will still result in the same error.